# Get all combination of list with repeated values

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

How can i get a list of all possible values of a list with also repeated ones?

I've tried `itertools.combination_with_replacement` and `itertools.permutation` but the first exclude the inverted order (such as `[3, 2, 1]`) and the second exclude multiple values (such as `[3, 3, 1]`).

I need something like this:

Example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]

results =
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
...
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
...
```

What can I do in Python to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), setting the repetition to 3:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(product(lst, repeat=3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```